# Setting up controller and its actions for Admin login only, not for a Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, admin

I have a model called `Article`.

In my `ArticlesController`, I have the article actions set up to where you have to be logged in as a User before you can do any actions except for my `index` and `show` actions.

Here's my `articles_controller.rb`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])

        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end

    private

    def article_params
        (params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text))    
    end
end
```

How can I set the `Article` actions so that **only** the **admin** can do basic CRUD functionality (create/read/update/delete) on `Article`?

Do I make an `Admin` model with `Devise` (I don't currently have an admin model)?

Is there a function or method that comes with `Devise` for admin usage in a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you're using a gem or rolling your own authorization, I would approach this by creating an additional controller. For regular users:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :some_basic_authorization

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  ...
end
```

Your admin users will probably be doing more than performing CRUD actions for an article, so instead of repeating authorization in every controller, I'd suggest doing something like the following:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  some_admin_authorization
end
```

You'll then create dedicated admin controllers and inherit from this authorizing class. In your case, this might look like:

```
class AdminArticlesController < AdminsController

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  ...
end
```

Only admins will have access to actions specified in these controllers. As a side benefit, you can create custom show and index views that are specialized and more useful for admins. For example, they would include big edit and delete buttons that regular users don't need. This also keeps authorization logic and if/else statements out of your views.

In my opinion, using separate controllers and authorizing admins in one place makes code more readable and creates a nice separation of concerns. Read more about this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-basic-authentication

You can take this one step further by using an admin namespace, which you can read about here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: After reviewing your comments and the links to the guides in your comments, I found that this way of authorizing certain actions was the perfect for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 4):

I think [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) would be a better option here.

After installing the gem and generating `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, Article
    else
      can :read, Article
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can check for ability in your view:

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

---

If you are using `Rails 4` onwards check [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) as the original `CanCan` was abandoned(Thanks [carpet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3748155/carpet)).

Comment: For Rails 4 [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) should be used as the original CanCan was abandoned.

Comment: @carpet I have modified my answer. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Lahirau I haven't checked out the `CanCanCan` gem yet, but hopefully when I check it out, it'll work for me! Thanks!